# Как запретить пустые значения при выводе из api, составленном из массива большой вложенности?

Tags: php, массивы, api, if, условия

уважаемые эксперты!

Вывожу из api значения-объекты "на фронт". Условие для "Совладельцев" подгружает из API вместе с нужными данными пустые значения (как это выглядит - приложил картинку внизу).

```
   foreach ($history_egrul[data] as $key => $value) { 
                                          foreach ($value[changes] as $key1=> $value1) {
                                   if($value1[title][value]=='uchr_dol' || $value1[title][value]=='uchr') {
                                       $history_fns['Совладельцы'][$value1[grn_date]][delete][$xq] = $value1[val_old];

                                    $history_fns['Совладельцы'][$value1[grn_date]][add][$xq] = $value1[val_new];
                             }
                                          
                                     if($value1[title][value]=='ruk') {
                               $history_fns['Руководитель'][$value1[grn_date]][delete][$xq] = $value1[val_old];   
                                $history_fns['Руководитель'][$value1[grn_date]][add][$xq] = $value1[val_new];   
                             }
```

Вот как выглядит внешне проблема:

[![введите сюда описание изображения][1]][1]

А вот схема работы api:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Моя проблема в том, что я не совсем понимаю, как обратиться к отдельным элементом api, чтобы добавтьб соответствующее условие..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Надеюсь правильно вас понял. Вам нужно просто при выводе добавить условие на проверку не пустое ли значение

```
$array = array(
    'array1' => array('name' => 'test1','test'=>'test1'),
    'array2' => array('name' => 'test1','test'=>'test1'),
    'array3' => array('name' => null,'test'=>'test1'),
);
    


foreach ($array as $key => $value){
    
    if(!$value['name'] == null){
        print_r($value);
    }

}
```